# enable CORS to call JSON REST from Cordova App

Tags: json, wordpress, cordova, rest, cors

I'm making an app with apache cordova ... and I need to take the post from a wordpress site .

Please , before you say it is a duplicate read the points below :

1. So , I installed Rest Api v2 : http://v2.wp-api.org/
2. enabled the cors like this: 
   `< ? header ( " Access- Control-Allow -Origin : * " ) ; ? >` In header.php of the theme , also even in `wp-content/plugins/json-api/singletons/api.php`
3. i have try install this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-cors/
4. call this method for GET REST API:

   ```
                 jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "myURL",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                         alert("suucess");
                    }

                });
   ```

the result is always the same , firebug returns me that CORS is locked , so I can not make demands from an external ... how do I fix ??

Answer (score 0):

Hi there's no need to add it to your theme header, just add the code below to **wp-content/plugins/json-api/json-api.php** file inside the **json_api_init()**  function

> ```
>    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
>    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
>    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');    
>    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS"); 
>    }   
>
>  // Accept Cross Domain Transfer.
>    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
>    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
>    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         
>    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
>    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:{$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
>    exit(0);
>    }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

i have solved change `DataType: "json"` to `DataType: "jsonp"`

> Solution: set DataType to jsonp.